# Managing assets for different areas with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to have different assets for different areas of a site in Rails. For example, in my `admin` area, I'm using `bootstrap` but this is getting loaded in non admin areas too. I guess it's to do with my folder structure but I've tried moving it and haven't really had any luck.

Anything `admin` related is where you'd expect a normal controller, view or asset except it's nested within an `admin` folder. E.g.

```
App > Assets > Stylesheets > Admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the asset pipeline to whatever you require.
described in detail here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

also here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Note in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js this little line:

```
//= require_tree .
```

which instructs sprocket to load all files in your assets javascript folder tree.  Change this this line to limit to specific files.